# Applying datetime format in pandas for sorting

Tags: python, sorting, datetime, pandas

In Pandas, I have column with dates of format: %Y/%m/%d (e.g. 2015/10/31). I want to change this format to another like: %d-%m-%y (e.g. 31-10-15).

Turning the column into the correct object for later sorting:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Applying strptime:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x:
    datetime.strptime(x,'%d-%m-%y'))

TypeError: must be str, not Timestamp
```

Also, oddly, if the dates enter pandas dataframe in anything other than the default ISO standard then weird results occur on sorting. Such as inconsistent formats and/or not properly sorting:

```
0  2015-01-31
1  2016-15-01
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to one part of the question:

> I want to change this format to another like: %d-%m-%y (e.g. 31-10-15).
>
> ... If the dates enter pandas dataframe in anything other than the default ISO standard then weird results occur on sorting. Such as inconsistent formats and/or not properly sorting

is actually really simple. Pandas was having issues because it considers the dd-mm-yy format international and an additional dayfirst argument must be entered for it to be treated properly:

`df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst = [True])`

May also need this (currently works for parsing data but not displaying):

`pd.set_option('display.date_dayfirst', True)`

Answer (score 2):

Because you are dealing with a datetime object already, you are getting this error because `strptime` requires a string and not a `Timestamp` object. From the definition of `strptime`:

```
def strptime(cls, date_string, format):
        'string, format -> new datetime parsed from a string (like time.strptime()).'
```

What you are actually looking to do is first convert your datetime to the format you require in to a string using `strftime`:

```
def strftime(self, format):
        """Return a string representing the date and time, controlled by an
        explicit format string.
```

and then bring it back to a `datetime` object using `strptime`. The following demo will demonstrate. Note the use of `.date()` at the end in order to remove the unneeded `00:00:00` time portion.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> orig_datetime_obj = datetime.strptime("2015/10/31", '%Y/%m/%d').date()
>>> print(orig_datetime_obj)
2015-10-31
>>> print(type(orig_datetime_obj))
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
>>> new_datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(orig_datetime_obj.strftime('%d-%m-%y'), '%d-%m-%y').date()
>>> print(new_datetime_obj)
2015-10-31
>>> print(type(new_datetime_obj))
<type 'datetime.date'>
```

Alternatively, if all you require is just converting it to a different format but in a string, you can simply stick to just using `strftime` with your new format. Using my example above, you would only need this portion:

```
orig_datetime_obj.strftime('%d-%m-%y')
```

Comment: @Prof I noticed you removed the accepted answer. Is there a particular problem? Or was there an easier way to solve this in pandas? I'm asking out of curiosity :)

Comment: I unaccepted the answer just now because I realised that I wasn't clear with my question. My code consists of a string with `.strptime` applied to it and then `.strftime` used to change it to the correct format. However, Pandas does not sort the columns with respect to date properly so I have to use a format that is sorted properly above. This format is `'%Y/%m/%d'`. Using this format instead, Pandas sorts the columns properly. But I'd like it to be sorted and then have the values return to the format originally desired: `'%d-%m-%y'`.

Comment: So I feel the format change must happen either inside the `.to_datetime` or the `df[].apply`. You realised that I unaccepted before I could finish, my apologies!

Comment: Have you got any ideas?

Comment: Apologies. Didn't mean to leave you hanging. For the order of data when changing the format, I am not too sure tbh. I actually don't use pandas all that much. Sorry. =/